# Font of the HTTP URL of the web application developed in GWT

Tags: gwt, web-applications

How do I get to know the font of the HTTP URL of the web application developed in GWT ?

For example the font of this in the address bar at the top:

```
http://192.168.7.100/ProjectName.html
```

I tried firebug but it cannot find the font of the URL.

Comment: Uhhh are you trying to style the browser's address bar?

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the plugin FontFinder for FireFox?

Quite easy, select the text, right button>FontFinder>Analyze Selection.

Check by yourself [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-finder/)

UPDATE: I have not used but WhatFont looks like similar in Chrome [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm)